# Insert multiple row in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle Application Express. I created a table named Employees. I want to insert multiple rows values by a single command . I used this command

```
INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES(
(100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',TO_DATE('06-17-1987','MM- DD-YYYY'),'AD_PRESS',24000,NULL,NULL,90),
(101,'Neena','Kochar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',TO_DATE('09-21-1989','MM-DD-YYYY'),'AD_VP',17000,NULL,100,90),
);
```

and I got **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis** error . Where is my mistake ? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid syntax in `Oracle`;

To insert multiple rows one can use `union all` or `insert all`

```
insert into tbl (
select val1, val2 from dual
union all
select val2, val4 from dual 
....
);
```

or

```
insert all 
into tbl(clm1, clm2) values (val1, val2)
into tbl(clm1, clm2) values (val3, val4)
....
select 1 from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Employees
select 100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',TO_DATE('06-17-1987','MM- DD-YYYY'),'AD_PRESS',24000,NULL,NULL,90
union select 101,'Neena','Kochar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',TO_DATE('09-21-1989','MM-DD-YYYY'),'AD_VP',17000,NULL,100,90
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do an INSERT ALL

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm

```
INSERT ALL 
  INTO Employees (cols) values (100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',TO_DATE('06-17-1987','MM- DD-YYYY'),'AD_PRESS',24000,NULL,NULL,90)
  INTO Employees (cols) values (101,'Neena','Kochar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',TO_DATE('09-21-1989','MM-DD-YYYY'),'AD_VP',17000,NULL,100,90)
select * from dual
```